# Expecting One line as output for the python 3 script but the result is varying

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python

I am trying to solve this problem. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index/problem

my code is here.

```
def palindrome(s):
    string = ''
    if s == s[::-1]:
        print(-1) # return -1
    else:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            string = s[:i]+s[i+1:]
            if string == string[::-1]:
                print(i) # return i
                break
            else:
                if(i+1 == len(s)):
                    print(-1) # return -1
```

when I submitted the above code, I got some test cases passed and 3 test cases are "time limit exceeded".

[image]

Then I have gone through this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd4hCrbYAMg and tried the code given in the video as below.

```
def palindromeIndex(s):
    if s == s[::-1]:
        print(-1) # return -1
    
    n = len(s)
    
    for i in range(n//2):
        if s[i] != s[n-1-i]:
            if s[i:n-1-i] == s[i:n-1-i][::-1]:
                print(n-1-i) # return n-1-i
            elif s[i+1:n-i] == s[i+1:n-i][::-1]:
                print(i) # return i
    print(-1) # return -1
```

from the video, code above is successfully passed all test cases.

when I try to run above code in my terminal with plain text file with `.py` extension, it is giving 3 lines or 2 lines or 1line as a result for youtube linked script.

***My Question is about the script from video link(which is `palindromeIndex(s)`), Can anyone explain why is this happening please?***

example:

```
# palindrom.py

#!/bin/python3

#####################################################################
def palindromeIndex(s):
    if s == s[::-1]:
        print(-1)
    
    n = len(s)
    
    for i in range(n//2):
        if s[i] != s[n-1-i]:
            if s[i:n-1-i] == s[i:n-1-i][::-1]:
                print(n-1-i)
            elif s[i+1:n-i] == s[i+1:n-i][::-1]:
                print(i)
    print(-1)
#####################################################################   

#####################################################################
def palindrome(s):
    string = ''
    if s == s[::-1]:
        print(-1)
    else:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            string = s[:i]+s[i+1:]
            if string == string[::-1]:
                print(i)
                break
            else:
                if(i+1 == len(s)):
                    print(-1)
#####################################################################    
s = input()
print('########### result of the script from video link ##############')
palindromeIndex(s)
print('################ result of the script by me ###################')
palindrome(s)
print('###########################################')
```

```
$ python palindrome.py
yellow
########### result of the script from video link ##############
-1
################ result of the script by me ###################
-1
###########################################
$ python palindrome.py
red
########### result of the script from video link ##############
-1
################ result of the script by me ###################
-1
###########################################
$ python palindrome.py
azad
########### result of the script from video link ##############
3
2 # } Not Expecting
-1 # } Not Expecting
################ result of the script by me ###################
3
###########################################
$ python palindrome.py
pratap
########### result of the script from video link ##############
1
3 # } Not Expecting
-1 # } Not Expecting
################ result of the script by me ###################
1
###########################################
$
```